# Change the width inside of class from bootstrap

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Goal:
I want to add a code in css that shall be 700 and not 870 based on picture 2.

Problem:
Today, the value is 870 as a standard (picture 1) and I want to add 700 with usage of css.

Tried to do it but I failed.

Info:
Im using bootstrap v.2

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To avoid the use of `!important` (which I loathe unless it's absolutely necessary as it goes against the **Cascading** flow and philosophy of **Cascading** Style Sheets!), try styling the `span9` more specifically with parent / child selectors...

Is there a parent class you can use? Even if it's in the body tag? This will override BootStrap's styling.

CSS:

```
.parentclass .span9 {
    width: 700px;
}
```

Also definitely worth ensuring that your custom CSS file is referenced AFTER your BootStrap files.

EDIT - To ensure your updated style works with BootStrap's defined viewports, use `@media` queries as follows:

```
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
    .parentclass .span9 {
        width: 700px;
    }
}
```

Please note that BootStrap 2 also has the following media query which effect `span` classes for the following:

```
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 979px)
```

In this @media query, `.span9` goes to 538px, so feel free to update this if need be... Simply do the same thing:

```
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 979px) {
    .parentclass .span9 {
        width: XXXpx;
    }
}
```

Below this (767px), span classes go full width (100%), so no need to add any more...

Comment: You will need to consider @media queries too, it probably will not work, as  @media queries will override that CSS, but nice explanation on why not to use `!important`.

Comment: @Tarekis, very true - media queries will need to be taken into account. My answer is a top-level approach :-)

Comment: You might want to add that to your answer, i guess OP does not know about @media queries, he'll surely be thankful for a complete answer.